# How does routing in react router example section work?

Tags: react-router

I am trying to mimic the structure specified at react router examples section, especially the one with "huge-apps". My folder structure looks like the following.

```
project
--src
  --huge-apps
    --app.js
    --index.html
--index.html
--webpack.config.js
```

This varies only with one level from the structure inside react router examples sections, which is as follows:

```
examples
--huge-apps
  --app.js
  --index.html
--index.html
--webpack.config.js
```

My problem is that I have to specify my Root path as "/src/huge-apps" inside my router configuration in app.js under huge-apps folder. However, react router examples section has Root path specified only as "/" inside app.js file under huge-apps section.

Can someone help me understand how can I achieve similar setup where my root path under my "huge-apps" section can also be specified as "/"?

I cannot seem to figure out what am I missing here. My react router version 2.0.0-rc5

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The examples are using basenames. A basename is used (for browser history projects, they are completely unnecessary for hash histories) to specify the root directory to find a project at. All pathnames will then be considered to start with the basename.

You can add a basename to your project by [decorating your history](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/v3.0.0/docs/guides/Histories.md#examples). For example, if your URLs should start with `/huge-apps`:

```
import { useRouterHistory } from 'react-router'
import { createHistory } from 'history'

const history = useRouterHistory(createHistory)({
  basename: '/huge-apps'
})
```

Now, when you navigate to `/huge-apps`, inside of your application it would consider the location to be `/`. Similarly, the URL `/huge-apps/foobar` would be considered `/foobar` inside of your application.

You will, of course, have to have your server setup so that when a user requests any `/huge-apps/*` URL, it will serve your `index.html` file.

As an aside, you should upgrade your version of React Router, either to 2.8.1 or 3.0.0. Version 3 is the same as 2, but with any deprecated version 1 code removed.

Comment: This indeed fixed my issue. I was referring to examples section under tag (v2.0.0-rc5) which did not have basename support specified in the code. I am glad it works now. I also upgraded to 3.0.0 and everything seems to be working fine. Thanks @Paul S